# Can't import from specific folder in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, pycharm, unresolved-external

I have a project in PyCharm. There is one "main"-script that imports several other scripts. 4 out of 5 imports go fine, but for some reason, the 5th and final import produces and unresolved reference. See line number 10.

I figure it must have something to do with there NOT being a blue dot on the folder named "VAR5_speedlimit", but I can't figure out what it means.

[image: Screenshot of PyCharm]

Does anyone know why line number 10 generates an "unresolved reference"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the little green dot in your other "folders" but missing in the `VAR5_speedlimit` folder. The ones with little green/blue dot is **Python Package**, the one without is Directory. You import from **Python Package**, not Directory.

To solve it, make a Python Package instead of Directory. Right click on your project, choose Python Package.

Alternatively, in the existing Directory, create `__init__.py` in the directory